# JQuery .css not working with margin-left inside an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building an image slider, and once the last slide is reached it should reset. However, for some reason the "reset" line doesn't work. I can use JQuery to set the margin-left property outside of the if statement, but it doesn't work inside  of it. I'm sure it's something dumb I'm just missing, but I've been trying to debug it for hours.

```
var $sliderContainer = jQuery('.sliderContainer');

if ($sliderContainer) {
  var $slides = $sliderContainer.find('.slides');

  // Configs
  var currentSlide = 1;
  var width = 198.2;
  var animationSpeed = 800;

  function sliderReset() {
    if (currentSlide === 12) {
      $slides.css('margin-left', 0);
      currentSlide = 1;
      console.log(currentSlide);
    };
  };
};

$leftArrow.bind('click', function() {
          currentSlide--;
          $slides.animate({ 'margin-left': '+=' + width },animationSpeed);
          console.log(currentSlide);
          setTimeout(function(){
            sliderReset();
          }, 200)
      });

  $rightArrow.bind('click', function() {
      currentSlide++;
      $slides.animate({ 'margin-left': '-=' + width },animationSpeed);
      console.log(currentSlide);
      setTimeout(function(){
        sliderReset();
      }, 200)
  });
};
```

Comment: Realized after posting I accidentally omitted that...oops. Edited.

Comment: Are you seeing the console logs fom the click handlers?

Comment: You're animating in `800ms` but calling `sliderReset` in `200ms`?

Comment: Also your `animationSpeed` is `800`, where as your setTimeout is `200`.  So if you start the animation that last 800ms, and after 200ms you change the margin, it's likely that the animation will keep adjusting after that point.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was. Thank you!!!